# AngularJS/javascript converting a date String to date object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, date

Im stuck on a problem and would appreciate any help. I have read through lot of the discussions already but they dont seem to work for me.

```
//I have a date as a string which I want to get to a date format of dd/MM/yyyy
var collectionDate = '2002-04-26T09:00:00'; 

//used angularjs date filter to format the date to dd/MM/yyyy
collectionDate = $filter('date')(collectionDate, 'dd/MM/yyyy'); //This outputs 26/04/2002 as a string
```

How do I convert it to a date object? The reason I want to do this is because I want to use it in a google charts directive where one of the columns has to be a date. I do not want to have the column type as string:

eg:

```
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
                    data.addColumn('date', 'Dates');
                    data.addColumn('number', 'Upper Normal');
                    data.addColumn('number', 'Result');
                    data.addColumn('number', 'Lower Normal');
                    data.addRows(scope.rows);.................
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is what I did on the controller

```
var collectionDate = '2002-04-26T09:00:00';
var date = new Date(collectionDate);
//then pushed all my data into an array $scope.rows which I then used in the directive
```

I ended up formatting the date to my desired pattern on the directive as follows.

```
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
                    data.addColumn('date', 'Dates');
                    data.addColumn('number', 'Upper Normal');
                    data.addColumn('number', 'Result');
                    data.addColumn('number', 'Lower Normal');
                    data.addRows(scope.rows);
                    var formatDate = new google.visualization.DateFormat({pattern: "dd/MM/yyyy"});
                    formatDate.format(data, 0);
//set options for the line chart
var options = {'hAxis': format: 'dd/MM/yyyy'}

//Instantiate and draw the chart passing in options
var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart($elm[0]);
                    chart.draw(data, options);
```

This gave me dates ain the format of dd/MM/yyyy (26/04/2002) on the x axis of the chart.

Answer (score 41):

try this

**html**

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  Hello, {{newDate | date:'MM/dd/yyyy'}}!
</div>
```

**JS**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    var collectionDate = '2002-04-26T09:00:00'; 

    $scope.newDate =new Date(collectionDate);
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gumarelo/9q655z8q/4/)

Answer (score 9):

I know this is *in* the above answers, but my point is that I think *all* you need is

```
new Date(collectionDate);
```

if your goal is to convert a date string into a date (as per the OP "How do I convert it to a date object?").

Answer (score 5):

```js
//JS
//First Solution
moment(myDate)

//Second Solution
moment(myDate).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss')
//or
moment(myDate).format('YYYY-MM-DD')

//Third Solution
myDate = $filter('date')(myDate, "dd/MM/yyyy");
```

```html
<!--HTML-->
<!-- First Solution -->
{{myDate  | date:'M/d/yyyy HH:mm:ss'}}
<!-- or -->
{{myDate  | date:'medium'}}

<!-- Second Solution -->
{{myDate}}

<!-- Third Solution -->
{{myDate}}
```