# create date object from string in angualrjs

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am working with angularjs and the angularjs bootstrap ui (http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/).

I want to use the datepicker directive (http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/datepicker).

I am getting a string value from a database

```
2015-07-30 15:10
```

Angular wants to have a date object as model but I wasnt able to create a date object with that string. the error I get is

***Error: [ngModel:datefmt]*** http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.3/ngModel/datefmt?p0=2015-07-30

Can anyboy help me create a date object in angular with a string which has this format -> **YYYY-MM-DD**

more Information:
the string is in my scope

```
$scope.event.startdate
```

and I am splitting it in date, hours and minutes.

```
$scope.startpoint = {
            date: $scope.event.startdate.substring(0, 10),
            hours: $scope.event.startdate.substring(11, 13),
            mins: $scope.event.startdate.substring(14, 16)
        };
```

The database is MongoDB

Thank you
Adrian

Comment: when you get it from the database are you getting it into the modle with `$scope` or just storing it in a var? also how are you getting it from the database? Is the database SQL or BSON?

Comment: I have updated my post with the requested information. cheers

Comment: You can consider using momentjs instead of splitting it manually

Comment: you don't need to split it at all just take the value as it stands and use the date formatter built into angular. Maybe I'm missing something but that should work.

Comment: I use event.startdate (string - 2015-07-30 15:10) as ngModel, but get this error -> Error: [ngModel:datefmt] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.3/ngModel/datefmt?p0=2015-07-30. So I need to defined this somehow to an date object which I dont know how to do

Comment: what angular function are you using that requires a date format, I would have thought that `var` would do everything.

Answer (score 3):

You can use use a generic javascript solution.  For example, you can use [serega386's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5619202/converting-string-to-date-in-js/16235315#16235315) to a [similar javascript question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5619202/converting-string-to-date-in-js):

```
var st = "26.04.2013";
var pattern = /(\d{2})\.(\d{2})\.(\d{4})/;
var dt = new Date(st.replace(pattern,'$3-$2-$1'));
```

Comment: Please do not plagiarize.  Read this on [How to Properly Reference other answers](http://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing).  You answer is a direct copy of [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16235315/4320665).  You need to give attribution to the other author and add some original content.

Comment: I've edited your answer to give better attribution to the original writer of this code.  Please include more explanation for this code to make your answer actually distinct.

Answer (score 1):

You can have the below code in your controller

```
$scope.newDate =new Date($scope.event.startdate);
```

and below code in your template

```
{{newDate | date:'yyyy-MM-dd'}}
```

Ref: [AngularJS/javascript converting a date String to date object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25027813/angularjs-javascript-converting-a-date-string-to-date-object)

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting the date as a single set of numbers like this

```
1288323623006
```

you can use the date formatter directly on that.(from angular doc [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date))

```
<span ng-non-bindable>{{1288323623006 | date:'medium'}}</span>:
<span>{{1288323623006 | date:'medium'}}</span><br>
<span ng-non-bindable>{{1288323623006 | date:'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z'}}</span>:
<span>{{1288323623006 | date:'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z'}}</span><br>
```

**Expected result**

[image: angular date format]

I hope that solves your problem, let me know if I'm missing something.

Comment: as mentioned, I have a string (2015-07-30 15:10), not an UNIX timestamp

Comment: Ah I see, sorry I was a little confused, misread. I'll see about fixing this.