# How to Convert date string?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

Convert the following date object , which is in string form to normal date format, in controller side.

```
  {"FromDate": "Wed Jan 02 2016 10:56:45 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)"}
```

Comment: using momment library to this.

Comment: no other solution with existing things?

Comment: may be help u http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25027813/angularjs-javascript-converting-a-date-string-to-date-object

Comment: Parse your date string using Date.parse() and then apply angular date filter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`var date = new Date(yourObject.FromDate)`

Check for browser compatibility.
Works in Chrome/Firefox.

Answer (score 1):

For Date conversions, you can use moment.js http://momentjs.com/ .

Answer (score 1):

```
$scope.FromData= "Wed Jan 02 2016 10:56:45 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)"

{{ $scope.FromDate | date : format : timezone}}
```